# Как в Semantic UI Accordion получить ID выбранного элемента

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Я использую модуль аккордион графической библиотеки Semantic ui.
Ссылка на официальную документацию этого модуля
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html

Вой мой HTML:

```
<div class="ui accordion"> <div id="id_1" class="title"> <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Title text 1 </div> <div id="id_content_1" class="content"> Content text 1 </div> <div id="id_2" class="title"> <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Title text 2 </div> <div id="id_content_2" class="content"> Content text 2 </div> </div>
```

я искал в гугле и нашел вот такой способ

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({ onOpening: function () { alert(this.index(".content")); console.log(this.index(".content")); } });
```

этот способ this.index(".content") возвращает мне 0 когда я кликаю по первому елементу или 1 когда кликаю по второму и т.д. но мне нужна именно айди елемента
"id_1" или "id_2"

надеюсь ктото сталкивался с этой библиотекой и этим модулем, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот сработало

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".ui.accordion" ).accordion({
        onOpening: function (e) {
            var target_id_text = this.attr("id");
        }
    });
});
```